# Solve trig equation: $\sin{(70^{\circ}-x)}=\frac{1}2 + \frac{1}{4\cos{(20^{\circ})}}$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

$$\text{Solve} \ \ \sin{(70^{\circ}-x)}=\frac{1}2 + \frac{1}{4\cos{(20^{\circ})}}$$
I came across this equation while solving a problem. The computer provides $x=20^{\circ}$, and I tried to draw a shape with that in mind:

[image]

Then I got the equation $\sin{(50^{\circ})}=2\sin{(20^{\circ})}\tan{(30^{\circ})}+\sin{(40^{\circ})}+\tan{(30^{\circ})}$.

Can this be somehow converted to $\frac{1}2 + \frac{1}{4\cos{(20^{\circ})}}$? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is $20^o$ the only answer$?$

Comment: Hint:
$$2\cos 20^\text{o}+1=2\cos 20^\text{o}+2\cos 60^\text{o}$$
We can then use sum and product formula for cosines.

Comment: there are infinite values of $x$
 and not just a single answer

Comment: An approach: do arcsin both sides

Comment: Another way of solution is calculating the RHS as follows: since $\cos(3x)=4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)$ then $\dfrac 12=4\cos^3(20^{\circ})-3\cos(20^{\circ})$ so $\cos(20^{\circ})=\dfrac{(2k+1)\pi}{9}$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$. Then the equation $\sin(70^{\circ}-x)=a$ where $a$ is the   constant $\dfrac12+\dfrac{9}{(2k+1)\pi}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the picture for geometric solution.

[image: solution]

Comment: After showing $\sin 50^\circ=\sin(70^\circ-x)$ one can easily find $x$.

Comment: I've missed to put into picture facts that angles ABC, CFD and AED are 90°.

Answer (score 8):

> $$\sin{(70^{\circ}-x)}=\frac12 + \frac{1}{4\cos{(20^{\circ})}}$$

Start from RHS:

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4\cos{(20^{\circ})}}&=\frac{2\cos(20^{\circ})+1}{4\cos(20^{\circ})}=\frac{2\sin(20^{\circ})\cos(20^{\circ})+\sin(20^{\circ})}{4\sin(20^{\circ})\cos(20^{\circ})}\\
\\
&=\frac{\sin(40^{\circ})+\sin(20^{\circ})}{2\sin(40^{\circ})}=\frac{2\sin(30^{\circ})\cos(10^{\circ})}{2\sin(40^{\circ})}\tag{1}\\
\\
&=\frac{\cos(10^{\circ})}{2\sin(40^{\circ})}
=\frac{\sin(80^{\circ})}{2\sin(40^{\circ})}\\
\\
&=\frac{2\sin(40^{\circ})\cos(40^{\circ})}{2\sin(40^{\circ})}\\
\\
&=\cos(40^{\circ})=\sin(50^{\circ})
\end{align}$$
We get:

$$\sin(70^{\circ}-x)=\sin(50^{\circ})$$

Therefore,

$$\boxed{x=20^\circ}$$

---

Note for eq.$(1)$, we use $\sin(a)+\sin(b)=2\sin(\frac{a+b}{2})\cos(\frac{a-b}{2})$.

Comment: Thank you sir. Can equality be shown in a geometrical way somehow?